# How can I upload a videofile under my youtube/google account while using a service account

Tags: java, youtube-api, google-oauth

I wish to create a server application that checks a folder on said server and automatically uploads any video files that have been dropped into said folder. The server is remote and no human interaction will take place.

After reading Youtube's API v3 guides I have come to the conclusion that I would need a "Service Account" to upload these videos since an application will constantly monitor this folder. My question is: Is it possible at all, to upload a video using a service account and then placing the video under my personal youtube account?

If this is in fact possible; I have created the following code but are confronted with an 401 Unauthorized (Invalid Token) error.

I have the following compilable source; I've tried to make it as small as possible:

```
package PACKAGE;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTubeScopes;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.PlaylistItem;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoSnippet;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoStatus;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class BigQueryTestApp {

  private static final String VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT = "video/*";
  private static final String SAMPLE_VIDEO_FILENAME = "sample_video.mp4";
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, GeneralSecurityException {

    final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
    File privateKeyFile = new File("privatekey.p12");

    GoogleCredential credential = new  GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
      .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
      .setServiceAccountId("XXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
      .setServiceAccountScopes(YouTubeScopes.all())
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(privateKeyFile)
      .build();


    try
    {

      YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("CHANGE_IT").build();
      Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();

      VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
      status.setPrivacyStatus("unlisted");
      videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(status);

      VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();

      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      snippet.setTitle("Test Upload via Java on " + cal.getTime());
      snippet.setDescription(
              "Video uploaded via YouTube Data API V3 using the Java library " + "on " + cal.getTime());

      List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
      tags.add("test");
      tags.add("example");
      tags.add("java");
      tags.add("YouTube Data API V3");
      tags.add("erase me");
      snippet.setTags(tags);

      videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);

      InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT,
              BigQueryTestApp.class.getResourceAsStream(SAMPLE_VIDEO_FILENAME));
      YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status", videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);
      MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();//thumbnailSet.getMediaHttpUploader();
      uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

      MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {

          public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException
          {
              switch (uploader.getUploadState())
              {
                  case INITIATION_STARTED:
                      System.out.println("Initiation Started");
                      break;
                  case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                      System.out.println("Initiation Completed");
                      break;
                  case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                      System.out.println("Upload in progress");
                      System.out.println("Upload percentage: " + uploader.getProgress());
                      break;
                  case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                      System.out.println("Upload Completed!");
                      break;
                  case NOT_STARTED:
                      System.out.println("Upload Not Started!");
                      break;
              }
          }
      };
      uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);

      // Call the API and upload the video.
      Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();

            // Print data about the newly inserted video from the API response.
            System.out.println("\n================== Returned Video ==================\n");
            System.out.println("  - Id: " + returnedVideo.getId());
            System.out.println("  - Title: " + returnedVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
            System.out.println("  - Tags: " + returnedVideo.getSnippet().getTags());
            System.out.println("  - Privacy Status: " + returnedVideo.getStatus().getPrivacyStatus());
            System.out.println("  - Video Count: " + returnedVideo.getStatistics().getViewCount());       
    }
    catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Headers: "+e.getHeaders().toString());
    }
```

Finally, I've read various stories about Service Accounts. Some say they are compatible with Youtube others say they are not. This confuses me and I've found more questions on stackoverflow which do not definitively speak wether it is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube does not support service accounts, and they have no plans to:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5370

One option for you, then, would be to set up your app to do an initial oAuth flow (which you initiate with user interaction one time), and then as part of that flow you'll be issued both a temporary access token and a refresh token. The refresh token can be used to get more access tokens without having to run the oAuth flow once again, and the refresh token won't expire on its own (it can be revoked manually, though). So your app could store your refresh token, monitor your folder, and then get an access token on its own whenever needing to upload a new video. See this link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#standalone

(note it specifically mentions the idea of a daemon that monitors a directory for new videos to upload).